# Finding an angle $\theta$ in a complex number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

If we know that $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\cos\theta+i\cdot\sin\theta)$ and also that $z = \frac{(\sqrt3-1)+i(\sqrt3+1)}{4}$

How can I find $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$? Using a calculator it gives me the angle $\frac{5\pi}{12}$. I tried the following:

$$\cos\theta = \frac{\Re z}{|z|} = \frac{\frac{1}{4}(\sqrt3-1)}{\frac{1}{\sqrt2}} = \frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\cdot\sqrt2}$$ How would I even proceed here, seems near-impossible without a calculator to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this as $r(\cos t+i\sin t)$

Using the definition of [atan2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation),  $0<t<\dfrac\pi2$

and $t=\arctan\dfrac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt3-1}=\arctan\dfrac{1+1/\sqrt3}{1-1/\sqrt3}=\arctan\dfrac{\tan45^\circ+\tan30^\circ}{1-\tan45^\circ\tan30^\circ}
$
$=45^\circ+30^\circ$

Hope you can find $r$ easily

Comment: I have just one question, I can see that the numerator can be written as $\tan 45 + \tan 30$ however, why is the denominator $1-\tan45\cdot\tan30$ and not just $\tan45-\tan30$ or $1-\tan30$?

Comment: @XMLParsing, What is $\tan(A+B)=?$ But, I think http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984416/am-i-going-about-this-wrong-complex-expression-to-polar-form/984430#984430 solves your problem of finding $t$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\cos(\frac{5\pi}{12}) = \cos(\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{3})=\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4})\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})+\sin(\frac{3\pi}{4})\sin(\frac{\pi}{3})=\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = $$ $$\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{2}}
$$

Now work backwards, amigo.

Answer (score 0):

see here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number
we have $\phi=\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)$